# npm create svelte@latest not working correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, svelte

When I try to use `npm create svelte@latest` to create a SvelteKit app it won't work when using VS Code with SSH.

The SSH server I'm connected to runs Ubuntu 20.04.2 on 64 bit Intel hardware.

When I try to use `npm create svelte@latest .` to initialize a SvelteKit project it outputs an error:

```
import fs from 'fs';
       ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Any way to fix this? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the output of `node --version`? You'll want to be on _at least_ around 12, but 18 is a good bet.

Comment: @ZacAnger v10.19.0

Comment: See my answer — you're gonna have to update, and because Ubuntu 20 doesn't have a recent version of Node, you'll have to do it with a third-party package. `nvm` and `n` work pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update Node. The latest in Ubuntu 20 is v10, which is very outdated. If you're not in a position to update your system to Jammy or Kinetic, you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) another version manager to get yourself up to date. Personally I like `n`:

```
npm i -g n
n stable
```

Comment: Updating fixed the issue. It took a while but it worked! Thanks!